# Integrating Twilio-js in Angular.js?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

Can anyone please guide me how do I integrate/require twilio.js file in the my application? I have to do it with `angular.js` app. I can't require/include it and can't get the `Twilio` object to call it's methods. I'm really new to it!

By just adding following script tag do not makes me able to use `Twilio` object:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.4/twilio.js"></script>
```

Results:

[image]

> Update:

As per @philnash help I've resolved the previous error and now this is how my code looks like is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.4/twilio.js"></script>
<script>
Twilio.Device.setup(@token, { debug: true, region: "ie1" });
Twilio.Device.ready(function(device) {
    // The device is now ready
    alert("Twilio.Device is now ready for connections");
});
</script>
```

But I'm getting the below error:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When using the [Twilio Client JavaScript](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js), there is no `Twilio.setup` function.

Instead, you should use [`Twilio.Device.setup`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#twilio-device).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: thanks for your response! But after using `Twilio.Device.setup('token')`, now its giving me an error in console `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at objectize (twilio.js:6055)` and the code at mentioned line is `var scopes = (jwt.scope.length === 0 ? [] : jwt.scope.split(' '));`. I'm using [v1.4](//media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.4/twilio.js).

Comment: Not entirely sure what's going on there. Can you share the code you're using? It's best to update your question and then let me know in the comments when you've done so. Cheers!

Comment: Ok, cool. So what is `@token` in this case? You should be generating a [capability token](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/capability-tokens) that you generate on your server and fetch from the front end.

Comment: that's the point! I need to use [capability-tokens](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/capability-tokens) and I was using the token for voice at this place. Its working now! Thanks a lot for your great help!